# Client won an award using our product, how to mention on CV

Tags: resume, clients

In my last role, a client won an independent industry award using a tech start up product we developed. As part of using the product they partnered with us, but at the award ceremony due to admin error we were not joint winners.

I was a key point of contact for the client as Product manager of the Product they used, and helped them set up and launch their campaign.

Can I mention on my CV that the Product won an award via the client?

Thanks

Comment: not sure if it would be relevant then, but you could always mention you were product manager for a product that eventually won an award. Wouldn't mean anything to me if I was interviewing, but every bit counts

Comment: I was the Product manager when it helped our client win the award, which was largely down to the work we did for the client by introducing improvements to the product enabling them to launch their campaign.

Comment: @bobo2000 didn't you ask this question a couple of days ago?

Comment: @SaggingRufus that was another industry award which I won recently in my new role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I mention on my CV that the Product won an award via the client?

Yes, you can.

Include it as a bullet point under the heading for the job you held at the time.

Hopefully it will be a talking point during an interview. There, you can expand on the value of the product to that client, and your role in making the product what it was.

Comment: "Product manager  of Awesometool, including for the award-winning ClientCorp" is how I would include it.